# OS X Cocoa Color Combo Box

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm currently learning to program for OS X / iOS and I'm trying to create a **Color Combo Box** for my first OS X app *(something like you can see in the image below)* but I have no idea how to do it and can't find any help or hint in Internet.

[image]

Can you please help me to understand which kind of object (visually speaking) I have to choose for my UI and then how to use it with an array of color values to create a session history?

Thank you!

Comment: if you need a static color combobox, would you rather have a pull down menu button?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your question @lead. I'm looking for a pull down menu button to check how it looks in OS X but I can't find anything. Remember I'm totally new with OS X development so sometimes I don't understand some terminology.

Comment: Jay's answer is how I would solve this.

Comment: You are not supposed to say here "I don't know how to do it.  Show me how". -1

Comment: @El Tomato did you miss the "help me to understand" part?

Comment: No, I did not.  Have you missed reading Help Center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the control you're looking for is a `NSPopUpButton`.
([NSPopUpButton Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSPopUpButton_Class/Reference/Reference.html), [Application Menu and Pop-up List Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/MenuList.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000032i))

Depending on what you're actaully trying to achieve using `NSAttributedStrings` in your menu items with the background color you desire would be an option, e.g.

```
string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"MyString"
              attributes:@{NSBackgroundColorAttributeName : [NSColor brownColor]}];
```

Check e.g. [here](http://cocoafactory.com/blog/2012/10/29/how-to-use-custom-nsattributedstring-attributes/) for details on how to work with attributed strings.

Comment: Could I customize the Pop Up Button content (list) with color swatches, so people can choose their option based in the color they choose before?

Comment: if you really want color swatches, use NSComboBox and set the dataSource to be your custom class, and implement 


    -(id)comboBox:(NSComboBox *)aComboBox objectValueForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index;


And provide a custom view which fills its background with a given color.